# ionic header bar disappears after reloading the state in angularjs

Tags: ionic-framework

I am working on a project where I need to use a messaging system.

I have an inbox: When I used the `$state.reload()` to show the newly sent message but when the state gets reloaded the header bar gets disappeared and doesn't gets visible until i do the manual refresh. I am using ionic 1.1.1 version

I searched a lot but didn't get any suitable reason that why it is happening. Kindly suggest me on this.

Comment: I'll advise you upgrade to the latest ionic > 1.1.X version which has lots of bug fixes.

Also, I think you can do without the page reload to show new messages

Comment: thanks for the reply and i will update the ionic.
can you please just tell me how can i get new messages without reloading the page?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, after searching a lot for ways to solve this problem, that I am also stuck on, I found out there is not! Unfortunatelly updating to the new version of Ionic did not help, and the workaround provided at Ionic's GitHub desn't work for me. It is:

```
$scope.$on('$ionicView.enter', function(e) {
    $ionicNavBarDelegate.showBar(true);
});
```

But if you have custom buttons in your header, this code doesn't work as expected. There are some jQuery solutions too, but I think it's not what we really need.

Source: https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/issues/3852

**EDIT**

So, I've worked on a pure Javascript solution, for my situation, and here it is. Hope it can help.

```
$scope.$on('$ionicView.enter', function(e) {
  $timeout(function() {
    showHeader();
  }, 1000);

  function showHeader() {
    // Having the nav-bar in your template, set an ID to it.
    var header = document.getElementById('header_id');
    if (header.classList) {
      if (header.classList.contains('hide')) {
        header.classList.remove('hide');
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: thank you good sir :) been struggling with this for months and I almost gave up on this. hilarious to find that the problem was a CSS class, LOL!

Comment: @Nexus I'm a Lady, sir! Hahaha! Glad to help.

Comment: honest mistake, madam! haha thank you. Still having this issue, didn't work on device. I'm testing on iPhone 8 for some reason the code fails to find the element and remove the 'hide' class.

Comment: Good to know, I will try to test on this device and see what happens.

Comment: @Nexus I did some tests with many types of IPhones and they all worked... just to be sure, did you added the ID to the right element? Like `<ion-nav-bar class="bar-positive" id="nav-bar">`

Comment: thanks a ton Laura. Yes the ID is correctly placed but I didn't get any luck last time. I'm working on this tomorrow first thing, I'll let you know if I could fix it. Fab, cheers.

Answer (score 1):

For me what was causing that issue came from the solution of this problem:
https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-v1/issues/119

Once i removed this line:

```
$ionicConfigProvider.views.maxCache(0);
```

from my config phase the action bar started to work again.

Comment: interesting, because I've had disabled caching on the home screen. many thanks, I'll give it a try and get back to you.